# Registered RendezvousChannel bean cannot be found within Spring Application Context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

In a Spring Boot application, we´re using a request-reply pattern by leveraging the `RendezvousChannel` from Spring Integration. When we receive a request, we create a uniquely named channel and register it within the Spring application context as follows:

```
RendezvousChannel rendezvousChannel = MessageChannels.rendezvous(uniqueId).get();
ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) springContext;
SingletonBeanRegistry beanRegistry = configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();
beanRegistry.registerSingleton(uniqueId, rendezvousChannel);
```

We then add this channel name to the request and do some work that takes some seconds. Then the response to this request arrives and is routed into the `RendezvousChannel`:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(globalChannel)
            .route("payload['replyChannel']")
            .get();
}
```

This works great and we receive the response to the request as desired.
But under load, when lots of temp. `RendezvousChannels` are created, the routing sometimes fails with:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to resolve channel name 'uniqueId'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'uniqueId' in the BeanFactory.; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'uniqueId' available, failedMessage=GenericMessage...
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.resolveChannelForName(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:227)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addChannelFromString(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:258)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.addToCollection(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:282)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMappingMessageRouter.determineTargetChannels(AbstractMappingMessageRouter.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:171)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:426)
```

Currently I´m not sure why this happens. Any ideas on this?

Comment: It's hard to say from here what's going on, but feels like a race condition: you try to send to the channel which has not registered yet or removed already. Would be great if you share some simple project on GitHub to let us to play with it.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I´m trying to reproduce the error in a small demo project. But right now I cannot reproduce it. I´ll invest some more time and see if it´s possible. Any other ideas I should look into?

Comment: My first concern why don't you use a built-in `replyChannel` header based request-reply implementation. Another problem that after using those dynamically-registered beans you need to ensure that you remove them from the application context.

Comment: @ArtemBilan We use this approach because we need the name of the replyChannel serialized as JSON within the backend of the system. Right now, just the message payload is serialized, not the header fields... But it seems to be worth thinking about that again.
The temp. bean is removed in a finally-block and the end of the processing of the request.

Comment: OK. I see your point. Let me think a bit and I'll come back to you with some solution without that `RendezvousChannel` and even `router`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I´ll give it a try later. BTW: the missing channel in the Spring context as stated above is fixed now. It was a hidden exception which caused the finally-block to run and thus destroying the singleton channel bean. It´s fixed now and works as expected. But anyway, I´ll try your solution for the answer :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For request-reply scenarios we recommend to use a `@MessagingGateway`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway

This one populates a `TemporaryReplyChannel` instance into the headers under the `replyChannel` key. Before sending to some outbound, external service you need to use something like this in your `IntegrationFlow`:

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerChannelsToString())
```

This way the mentioned `TemporaryReplyChannel` is stored in some specific `HeaderChannelRegistry`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-channel-registry

After that you really can provide some `transform()` to pack a `replyHeader` into the payload according your requirements. For this purpose, by the way, we provide something like `EmbeddedJsonHeadersMessageMapper`, which can be used from the mentioned `transform()` as a plain POJO consumer.

When you receive a reply, you should ensure that at least required `replyChannel` property comes together with the actual reply payload. In this case you again can use  `EmbeddedJsonHeadersMessageMapper.toMessage()` to remap embedded headers back to the `MessageHeaders` or you need to ensure the remapping by yourself. What is important that you have to populate a `replyChannel` header in this case. In the end you can just reply on the standard mechanism to send an output to the `replyChannel` from header. The mentioned above `HeaderChannelRegistry` will ensure resolution of the string id to the actual `TemporaryReplyChannel` instance meanwhile a gateway in the beginning will still wait for the value from that `TemporaryReplyChannel`.